# How to free the kernel of Symfony (PHP) used in the threads?

Tags: php, multithreading, symfony

In php 7.0.2, develop a symfony2 command in which two-level threads (fork) are created.

There is a Container class that instantiates the MyWorker class (extends from Worker) and calls the start () function for each MyWorker element in the $workers array.

With the call to the function start () of MyWorker the function run in which a Symfony instance is created, data is searched in the repositories, 5 children belonging to the MyThread class are created by each MyWorker and is called the function start () that invokes the run function.

In the run function of MyThread, Symfony is instantiated again (I did not find a way to do it through the parent instance).

```
    class Container
    {
        protected $user; 

        public function process()
        {
            $param = array();

            // ... Some logic

            $workers = array();
            for ( $j = 0; $j < 5; $j++ )
            {
                $workers[] = new MyWorker( $param );
            }

            /**
             * Process the workers
             */
            foreach ( $workers as $work )
            {
                $work->setUser($this->user);
                $work->start();
            }       

        }   
    }
```

---

```
    class MyWorker extends \Worker
    {
        protected $container;
        protected $document_manager;    
        protected $id;  

        public function __construct ( $param )
        {
            $id = $param['id'];
            //... Set other parameters
        }


        public function setDoctrineManagerInWorker()
        {
            //Set require Autoload and AppKernel
            require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/autoload.php';
            require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/AppKernel.php';

            //Creating a new AppKernel with the given environment
            $kernel = new \AppKernel( 'dev', 1 );
            //Loading the Cache and Classes
            $kernel->loadClassCache();
            $kernel->boot();

            //Set container
            $container = $kernel->getContainer();

            //Set document manager
            $document_manager = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        }


        public function run()
        {
            $this->setDoctrineManagerInWorker();        

            //... Aqui se aplica la logica para acceder a los repositorios

            $worker = $this->document_manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Worker')->find( $this->getId() );        

            //...

            for ( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ )
            {
               $thread = new MyThread( $param );
               $thread->start();
               $thread->join();
            }
        }
    }
```

---

```
    class MyThread extends \Thread
    {
        protected $container;
        protected $document_manager;    

        public function __construct ( $param )
        {
            //... Set parameters
        }

        public function setDoctrineManagerInThread()
        {
            //Set require Autoload and AppKernel
            require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/autoload.php';
            require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../app/AppKernel.php';

            $kernel = new \AppKernel( 'dev', 1 );
            //Loading the Cache and Classes
            $kernel->loadClassCache();
            $kernel->boot();
            //Set container
            $this->container = $kernel->getContainer();
            //Set document manager
            $this->document_manager= $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
        }

        public function run()
        {
            $this->setDoctrineManagerInThread();

            //... Logical processing of repositories
            $thread = $this->document_manager->getRepository('MyBundle:Thread')->findAll();
            //...
        }
    }
```

The problem is that when the process () function is called repeatedly (more than 200 times), the following memory error is generated:

```
mmap () failed: [12] Can not allocate memory. Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 2820669440) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /srv/www/leadpro.com/current/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Exception/OutOfMemoryException.php on line 1
```

I'm assuming that the error must be generated because symfony instances are not released within the Workers and Threads.

Please, if anyone can suggest a solution, I would be very grateful.